# Libgdx - Why is Bullet and FreeType is not compatible with HTML?

Tags: libgdx, bullet, freetype

I have attempted to do the following

[image: Generator Configuration]

When I tried to check either Bullet or FreeType or Both, the following pops up

[image: Warning]

I do not get why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bullet and FreeType libraries both depend on native code (C or C++) that isn't available in the HTML Libgdx backend.

The HTML Libgdx backend uses [Google's GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) project to cross-compile Java bytecodes into Javascript.  Thus, only Java code, or APIs that exist in both places can be used.  See http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2308 for more details.

Comment: Google has since introduced a [native API](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client), so this could be remedied.